# How to add a user-defined typecast for a variable in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion, typecast-operator

I have a class with functions that take `vector<double>` as input and also return `vector<double>`.

I want to overload this function to take `Eigen::vectorXd` as input and output. I have many functions that need to be overloaded. Is there a way to create a typecast which would typecast `Eigen::vecrtorXd` to `vector<double>` for all these functions?

Comment: You should use the buttons to mark code as `code.'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're looking for, you might be able to achieve this with a basic templated function, i.e.

```
template <typename vec_t>
vec_t do_something(const vec_t& input)
{
  // Do things
}
```

This works fine if you want to do something generic like calculate a norm where the dimension of the vector doesn't matter.

Comment: This is what I want, but how do I specify the conversion between `vector<double>` and `Eigen::VectorXd` since it is not an in-built conversion?

Comment: I don't know how Eigen works, but you can create a manual templated conversion function with signature `template <typename eigen_vec_t> std::vector<double> convert(const eigen_vec_t&)` and call it, assuming Eigen has some uniform way to iterate through the elements.